# How to convert this Angular js code into Angular 6 syntax?

Tags: angularjs, angular

We are trying to place a dynamic data inside the rows. Each row has 3 columns. We found this angular js code which looks like what we need. The point is that we are using angular 6. How can this angular js code be converted into angular?

```
<div ng-controller="ColumnsCtrl" class="container">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="person in persons" ng-if="$index % 3 == 0">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">{{persons[$index].name}} <span class="badge">{{persons[$index].age}}</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" ng-if="persons[$index + 1].name != null">{{persons[$index +
                1].name}} <span class="badge">{{persons[$index + 1].age}}</span></button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" ng-if="persons[$index + 2].name != null">{{persons[$index +
                2].name}} <span class="badge">{{persons[$index + 2].age}}</span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is pretty straight forward if you know Angular 6.  PS : Code doesn't need any major changes. Show where you are stuck or what you tried so far.

Comment: I am beginner. I assume that controller on the row class should be removed and what should be changed in this part?
ng-if="persons[$index + 1].name != null">{{persons[$index +
                1].name}} <span class="badge">{{persons[$index + 1].age}}</span>

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<div class="row" *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index" *ngIf="i % 3 === 0">
```

The rest can be repeated by replacing each `$index` with `i` and each `ng-if` with `*ngIf`.
You can also have a look at the `ngIf` and `ngFor` syntax [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngif).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your controller is set up appropriately and linked to this template, this should work:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index" *ngIf="i % 3 == 0">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block">{{person.name}} <span class="badge">{{person.age}}</span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" *ngIf="persons[$index + 1].name != null">{{persons[i +
              1].name}} <span class="badge">{{persons[i + 1].age}}</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" *ngIf="persons[i + 2].name != null">{{persons[i +
              2].name}} <span class="badge">{{persons[i + 2].age}}</span></button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```